How would I estimate uncertainty from a Monte Carlo simulation of a queuing model?
I am doing a Monte Carlo simulation of a complex service model that has deterministic and stochastic components. Here is a simplified description:

There are $\lambda_i$ calls per minute $i$, following a Poisson distribution
There are $n$ servers available
Call lengths follow a normal distribution with a specified mean and variance

There are different scenarios where parameters such as the rate of calls per minute or number of servers are varied.
I run a Monte Carlo simulation for each scenario where the simulation advances minute by minute, randomly drawing from a Poisson distribution for new calls, assessing if servers are available, assigning servers if available, assigning a call-length by drawing from a normal distribution, and ending calls (thus marking servers as available) at the end of the assigned call-length. Calls are dropped if no servers are immediately available.
I simulate this, as the actual model is a bit more complex, making estimation of closed form solutions difficult.
I run a 1000 iterations of the simulation from each scenario and estimate summary statistics (e.g. number of calls dropped). I then use median of these iterations and to estimate uncertainty, I am taking the 2.5th and 97.5th percentile of these simulations. Is this reasonable?
To understand the difference between two scenarios, can I take the difference in medians from the iterations for each scenario. How would I go about estimating the uncertainty for the difference in medians between two scenarios?

Yes, what you are doing is reasonable, though I would suggest upping the number of simulations to 10,000 or more if they can be done in a reasonable amount of time.
To estimate the uncertainty in the difference of medians, just take the medians from the first scenario minus the medians from the second scenario, keep them in simulation order, do not try sorting or reordering them (1,000 differences in the case of what you have already done) and then look at the 2.5th and 97.5th percentiles of the differences.
